# Arba'a Veshiv'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seventy-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

174 is the number of hours Chametz is prohibited by the Torah any year. 7 times 24 plus the last 6 hours of Passover Eve.

174 is also the numerical equivalent of the words כסף and זהב together. This is significant, together with the previous item, in explaining a verse in Psalms 105 37:

ויוציאם בכסף וזהב ואין בשבטיו כושל

See R' Zvi Elimelech of Dinov, Igra dPirka, 193, for the full treatment.

Comment: Beautiful answer... deserves the check!

Answer (score 1):

[Supposedly](http://books.google.com/books?id=9b7PAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA673&lpg=PA673&dq=174), 174 Jews (or maybe 174 American Jews?) won the *Croix de Guerre* in World War Ⅰ. (I don't know whether that includes the French and Belgian croix or just the French.)

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 Jewish months that have 29 days - Cheshvan (usually), Teves, Adar, Iyar, Tamuz, Ellul - 6 x 29 = 174